# How to adjust relations between entities using Hibernate mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have such a simple scheme

[image]

and the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Event event;
    @OneToOne
    private User user;
    @Embedded
    private Seat seat;
    private TicketState state;
    private Float price;
// getters, setters, etc.

@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @OneToOne
    private Movie movie;
    @Embedded
    private Auditorium auditorium;
    private LocalDateTime startDateTime;
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Ticket> tickets = new HashSet<>();
// getters, setters, etc.

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserRole role;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Instant birthday;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean lucky;
// getters, setters, etc.

@Embeddable
public class Auditorium {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer seatsNumber;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Integer> vipSeats;
// getters, setters, etc.
```

Also these entities was added to `hibernate.cfg.xml`.
Than I run app I have the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.epam.spring.core.domain.Event column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

At first glance I don't see any duplications in `Event`, as mentioned in exception. What should I fix in entities mapping description to resolve the problem according my scheme? Thank you!

Comment: What's in `Auditorium`?

Comment: Exactly the fields from picture - I need not separate table for auditoriums, so I just embed this information, the same for Seat's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Event` and `Auditorium` map to column named `id`.

Specify a different column name in `Auditorium` or use [`@AttributeOverride`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html) in `Event` to override the default name.

Comment: Perfect, app runs and entities are persisted, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When you map an entity with annotations, you do not need to repeat yourself on hibernate.cfg.xml. Try to delete it e run your code again.

Updating my answer based on Dragan Bozanovic's, Auditorium should NOT have an @Id annotated field (but we can't see that from your code, if it has).

Comment: Actually your suggestion helped - app started, but at first place in code where object was tried to be persisted I've got 'Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.epam.spring.core.domain.User'. So, it seems, entities should be mentioned in hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: @DmitriiAdonin, did you create your persistence.xml properly?

Comment: I think 'hibernate.cfg.xml' is enough, isn't it?

Comment: Should be, but if you want to use JPA annotations, the best practice is to embrace it, using only persistence.xml